# Semantic UI, remove autofoucs on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic ui dropdown within a modal box, whenever the modal is being opened, the dropdown in it opens automatically.

```js
function showmodal() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
}
if ($('.ui.dropdown').length) {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    useLabels: false,
    forceSelection: false,
    autoFocus: false
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Profile Picture
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <form action="" class="ui form">
      <div class="field mandatory">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select class="ui dropdown">
          <option value="">Gender</option>
          <option value="1">Male</option>
          <option value="0">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Nope
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
      Yep, that's me
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="ui button" onclick="showmodal()">Click to Open Modal</button>
```

I have tried `autoFocus: false`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `autoFocus: false` before the `modal('show')` :

```js
function showmodal() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal({
    autofocus: false,
  }).modal('show');
}
if ($('.ui.dropdown').length) {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    useLabels: false,
    forceSelection: false
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Profile Picture
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <form action="" class="ui form">
      <div class="field mandatory">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select class="ui dropdown">
          <option value="">Gender</option>
          <option value="1">Male</option>
          <option value="0">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Nope
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
      Yep, that's me
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="ui button" onclick="showmodal()">Click to Open Modal</button>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wvpqf9t2/

Comment: @AbhishekPandey happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is showOnFocus: False

```
$(function(){
    $('.ui.button').click(function(){ showmodal() })
  function showmodal() {
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  }
  if ($('.ui.dropdown').length) {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
      showOnFocus: false
    });
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q48s3voj/1/